# Flatten a non-linear list in lisp

Tags: list, linked-list, common-lisp, flatten

I want to flatten a list in Lisp, for example:

```
(1 2 (3 (4 5) 6)) --> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
(defun flatten (l)
    (cond
        ((endp l) nil)
        ((listp (car l)) (cons (flatten (car l)) (flatten (cdr l))))
        ((atom (car l)) (cons (car l) (flatten (cdr l))))))
```

I don't know what is wrong here. I even found on a forum the exact same code and the guy said that it is working but this code is not changing my list at all. Some help?

Comment: If `flatten` makes a list then `(cons (flatten..)...) ` makes a nested list.

Comment: In the case of (listp (car l)), you should use append, not cons. See more at the linked duplicate.